# Specialising a variadic template member function of a non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        void stuff(Args... args);
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void A::stuff(Args... args) {
        cout << sizeof...(args) << endl;
}

template<>
void A::stuff<int>() {
        cout << "int" << endl;
}

int main() {
        A a;
        A b;

        a.stuff<char>();
        b.stuff<int>();
}
```

[Trying to compile it](http://ideone.com/cuTtK), I get this error:

```
template-id 'stuff<int>' for 'void A::stuff()' does not match any template declaration
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried it without the variadicness and it worked, but how do I specialise a variadic template member function?

Comment: It looks good but I think the error has something to do with the fact that function templates cannot be partially specialized. I do not know how will you get the syntax right just by specializing the first parameter (T) and leaving out the `variadic` type (args).

Comment: @AdityaKumar I'm not partially specialising the template, it's fully specialised.

Comment: Yes i understand. I'm wondering if there is compiler support for it yet.

Comment: This compiles just fine on clang 3.2 What version of gcc are you on?

Comment: @dirkgently 4.7, guess it's a bug then.

Comment: I tried with gcc-4.6, didn't work

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Hm. Searching bugzilla. BTW: Just so you know, I compiled with `-Wall`, `-pedantic` on my clang *without* any errors.

Comment: @dirkgently, you may want to incorporate your comments as an answer. As this seems to be a gcc bug.

Comment: @iammilind: Hm. Done. Added more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug. The problem is not limited to fully-specialized member function templates. It can be reproduced even with free-function templates as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void stuff2(Args... args);

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void stuff2(Args... args) {
    cout << sizeof...(args) << endl;
}

template<>
void stuff2<int>() {
    cout << "int" << endl;
}
int main() {}
```

While clang 3.2 compiles this just fine, gcc complains about:

> spec.cpp:31:6: error: template-id 'stuff2' for 'void stuff2()' does not
>    match any template declaration

There is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767202/template-specialization-with-variadic-templates).

A [message](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-11/msg00240.html) seems to confirm that this is indeed a bug.

Comment: you can also add the current possible solution where the current problem can be solved by overloading the `stuff2()`.

Comment: @iammilind: That doesn't fix the OP's problem (which is about member function templates and not free function templates).

Comment: Already upvoted the answer but, still it can be solved at [some extent](http://ideone.com/2WimQ).

Comment: @iammilind: I think the correct expression is *to* some extent. I am afraid it may not solve the OP's issue as overload requires modifying the class definition, while specialization can be tacked on externally.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer because it answers the question, unfortunately iammilind's solution doesn't work for my situation (I can't have a default argument where the function can be called without a template argument). Hopefully this bug gets fixed quickly. Thanks.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Did you file one? If so, can you edit in the bug-reference?

Comment: @dirkgently no, I haven't filed a bug, I thought there already was one. Should I go ahead and do it?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I guess so. I couldn't find one.  If I had I'd have put it here :) But you shouldn't trust my google-fu entirely.