# C++ variadic template specialization (and static_assert)

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is it possible to specialize this template declaration:

```
template <class TYPE, class... ARGS> TYPE Foo(ARGS... args) { 
    static_assert(false);
}
```

I tried a few things such as:

```
template <> int Foo<int>(float args) {
    return 42;
}
```

...but I always hit the static assert when I try to use it as such:

```
auto value = Foo<int>(1.5f);
```

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Maybe it's just that your compiler doesn't support it just like in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767202/template-specialization-with-variadic-templates?rq=1 ?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Clang and MSVC does compile your code and `value` holds 42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As state, `false` is non template dependent, so the `static_assert` should fire.

You may use `= delete` in your case:

```
template <class TYPE, class... ARGS> TYPE Foo(ARGS... args) = delete;

template <> int Foo(float) {return 42;}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/GzyZJY)

Comment: Is not enough `template <class TYPE, class... ARGS> TYPE Foo(ARGS... args);` in this case?

Comment: @skypjack: It would be link error, whereas we may have compile error with `=delete`.

Comment: Works fine on live demo, however this does not work in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. I get `error C2280: attempting to reference a deleted function`.

Comment: Old versions of gcc/clang has also this bug, see [specialized-template-function-with-deleted-general-case-fails-to-compile-with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256589/specialized-template-function-with-deleted-general-case-fails-to-compile-with)

Answer (score 7):

You're not allowed to write a template that is only valid as long as it isn't instantiated. That runs afoul of the following rule in the standard:

> If no valid specialization can
>   be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

On the other hand, it would be fine if you had something in the body such as

```
static_assert(sizeof(TYPE) != sizeof(int));
```

In such a case, the template is valid, and your code will compile since the explicit specialization will in fact be used instead of the primary template. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/238b979fd10c62c0

Answer (score -2):

Your static assert does not depend on the template so it will always fire. Use something like

```
template <class TYPE, class... ARGS> TYPE Foo(ARGS... args) { 
    static_assert(sizeof(TYPE) != sizeof(TYPE));
}
```

Comment: This is equally bad even if a compiler doesn't currently diagnose it.

Comment: @T.C.: It does correctly diagnose it - the correct diagnosis for a failed `static_assert` is an error... As the standard states, the stage of the compilation which `static_assert` fails is in the template definition for non dependent expressions, and instantiation for dependent expressions. So if you would like a `static_assert` to fire only upon instantiation, make it dependent, even if the condition itself is not effected by the template arguments.

Comment: As no valid specialization of this template can be generated, a compiler is allowed to diagnose this at definition time. The quote is in Brian's answer.